# insertar datos de una api a otra api

Tags: php

Conseguí instalar una API para que los clientes se puedan suscribir, pero ahora tengo que pasar los datos del formulario de suscripción una vez validados a otra página, que en realidad es una página hecha también con otra API. ¿Cómo se podría hacer eso?

Creo que la función debo implementarla en el archivo que la API llama checkout.php:

```
$subscription = $result->subscription();
    // var_dump($subscription); 
    $queryParameters = "subscription_id=" . urlencode($subscription->id);
    $jsonResp["forward"] = "thankyou?" . $queryParameters;

    //echo json_encode($jsonResp, true);
    echo "<div class='respuesta'><h1>Thanks for subscribing</h1></div>";
    //  header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', false, 301);
    header("Location: https://aem-author-proda4.bmw.com/content/bmw/marketAT/bmw_at/de_AT/campaign/bmw-prime/thank-you.html?wcmmode=disabled" );
    exit();


} catch(ChargeBee_InvalidRequestException $e) {
    handleInvalidRequestErrors($e, "plan_id");
} catch(Exception $e) {
    handleGeneralErrors($e);
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola diego, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general). Leyendo tu pregunta, no termina de quedar claro qué quieres hacer o qué APIs estás usando. Deberías editarla para añadir eso y más información: ¿qué hace el código compartido? ¿por qué piensas que debes implementar el cambio ahí? ¿qué has investigado sobre el problema y qué has intentado?. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Todo depende de cómo hayas declarado el endpoint de tus APIs, cosa que debieras incluir en tu pregunta. Aunque tu pregunta está incompleta, alguien puede llegar con una duda similar y voy a dejar una respuesta que **a modo general** puede servir para lo que tú quieres, aunque dudo que se aplique directamente a tu caso particular.

**A modo general**, como dije, si el endpoint donde recibes la petición de subscripción está declarado como:

```
$app->post('/suscribir', function($request, $response) {

});
```

(Cosa que sería lo esperable si estás usando un framework o router que cumpla con [PSR-7](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/))

Puedes obtener los parámetros enviados a tu endpoint usando:

```
$app->post('/suscribir', function($request, $response) {
    $parametros = $request->getParsedBody();
});
```

Y como aparentemente estás usando [ChargeBee](https://apidocs.chargebee.com/docs/api/subscriptions#create_a_subscription), enviar esos parámetros haciendo:

```
$app->post('/suscribir', function($request, $response) {

  $parametros = $request->getParsedBody();

  $body = $response->getBody(); 

  try {

    ChargeBee_Environment::configure("{site}","{site_api_key}");
    $result = ChargeBee_Subscription::create($parametros);
    $subscription = $result->subscription();
    $status = 200;
    $msg = 'Subscripción exitosa: '.$subscription->id;

  } catch(ChargeBee_InvalidRequestException $e) {
    $status = 400;
    $msg = 'Hubo un problema: '.$e->getMessage();

  } catch(Exception $e) {
    $status = 500;
    $msg = 'Hubo otro problema: '.$e->getMessage();

  } finally {
    $body->write($msg);
    return $response
        ->withStatus($status)
        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'text/html')
        ->withBody($body);

  }
});
```

Si la petición a tu endpoint fuera hecha mediante ajax y esperases una respuesta en formato json, el bloque `finally`  debiera ser en cambio:

```
 return $response
        ->withStatus($status)
        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'text/html')
        ->withJson(['resultado'=>$msg]);
```

Mirando el código que pones, me parece que lo que te falta es parsear el primer payload (que recibes en tu endpoint) y luego manejar la respuesta.